# Отправка формы на чужом сайта

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть сайт [pulscen.ru](http://pulscen.ru), АПИ никакого нет, но хочется выгружать туда каталог автоматически. Можно ли как то сделать, чтобы со своего сайта вставлять в эту форму сслыку на файл и нажимать Загрузить? Может быть AJAX - запросом как-то, подскажите в какую сторону копать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: смотрите на какой адрес уходит запрос, затем формируйте такой же формат данных и шлите свой запрос из скрипта на этот адрес, например CURLом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройках можно включить автоматическое обновление yml прайса и время обновления. [Инструкция](http://www.pulscen.ru/about/site/import-yml) на их сайте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уже там нет такого, видимо старое описание

Comment: У Вас тариф размещения какой?

Comment: С тех. поддержкой пообщались, они исправляют, спасибо за ответ!